# Change CSS for specific serie label in legend in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I am building a column chart in highcharts, this chart will show the difference between past and current year KPI using 2 grouped stacked columns.

[image]

I made the previous year more transparent using `series.opacity` in 0.7:

```js
{
    name: 'Open 2021',
    data: [data_past_open],
    opacity: 0.7,
    stack: 'past'
},{
    name: 'Closed 2021',
    data: [data_past_clos],
    opacity: 0.7,
    stack: 'past'
},
```

The problem is this opacity is not affecting the legend:

[image]

So, what I am looking for, is a way to change the legend style for these specific series, with not using rgba() or hsla() colors.

This is a snippet:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container_flow', {
    colors: ['#F66','#999'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: undefined
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                let label;return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversedStacks:false,
        min: 0,
        title: {text: 'KPI'},
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 20,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y', new Date(this.x)) + '</b><br/>Hay:';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>: ' + this.y + ' ' + this.series.name;
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {enabled: true, }
        }
    },
    series: [
        
            {
                name: 'Open 2021',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-01'),10],[Date.parse('2022-02'),10],[Date.parse('2022-03'),15],[Date.parse('2022-04'),4],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),10],[Date.parse('2022-07'),13],[Date.parse('2022-08'),8],[Date.parse('2022-09'),8],],
        opacity: 0.7,
                stack: 'past'
            },{
                name: 'Closed 2021',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-10'),4],[Date.parse('2022-02'),11],[Date.parse('2022-03'),7],[Date.parse('2022-04'),7],[Date.parse('2022-05'),3],[Date.parse('2022-06'),7],[Date.parse('2022-07'),9],[Date.parse('2022-08'),2],[Date.parse('2022-09'),3],],
        opacity: 0.7,
                stack: 'past'
            },
            {
                name: 'Open 2022',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-01'),10],[Date.parse('2022-02'),10],[Date.parse('2022-03'),15],[Date.parse('2022-04'),4],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),10],[Date.parse('2022-07'),13],[Date.parse('2022-08'),8],[Date.parse('2022-09'),8],],
                stack: 'curr'
            },{
                name: 'Closed 2022',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-10'),5],[Date.parse('2022-02'),29],[Date.parse('2022-03'),29],[Date.parse('2022-04'),9],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),19],[Date.parse('2022-07'),28],[Date.parse('2022-08'),9],[Date.parse('2022-09'),19],],
                stack: 'curr'
            }   ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container_flow"></div>
```

The same in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stramin/odbvns6L/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this for you. Somehow it returns the expected result.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jqrmcu3b/1/)

```
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
        if (this.opacity == '0.7') {
        return '<span class="customPoints" style="background:'+this.color+'; opacity:0.5"></span><span style="opacity: 0.3;">' + this.name + '</span>';
      } else {
        return '<span class="points" style="background:'+this.color+'"></span><span>' + this.name + '</span>';
      }
    }
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container_flow', {
    colors: ['#F66','#999'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        margin: undefined
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                let label;return Highcharts.dateFormat('%B', this.value);
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        reversedStacks:false,
        min: 0,
        title: {text: 'KPI'},
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'white'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: 20,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        shadow: false,
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function() {
            if (this.opacity == '0.7') {
            return '<span class="customPoints" style="background:'+this.color+'; opacity:0.5"></span><span style="opacity: 0.3;">' + this.name + '</span>';
          } else {
            return '<span class="points" style="background:'+this.color+'"></span><span>' + this.name + '</span>';
          }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y', new Date(this.x)) + '</b><br/>Hay:';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>: ' + this.y + ' ' + this.series.name;
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {enabled: true, }
        }
    },
    series: [
        
            {
                name: 'Open 2021',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-01'),10],[Date.parse('2022-02'),10],[Date.parse('2022-03'),15],[Date.parse('2022-04'),4],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),10],[Date.parse('2022-07'),13],[Date.parse('2022-08'),8],[Date.parse('2022-09'),8],],
        opacity: 0.7,
                stack: 'past'
            },{
                name: 'Closed 2021',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-10'),4],[Date.parse('2022-02'),11],[Date.parse('2022-03'),7],[Date.parse('2022-04'),7],[Date.parse('2022-05'),3],[Date.parse('2022-06'),7],[Date.parse('2022-07'),9],[Date.parse('2022-08'),2],[Date.parse('2022-09'),3],],
        opacity: 0.7,
                stack: 'past'
            },
            {
                name: 'Open 2022',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-01'),10],[Date.parse('2022-02'),10],[Date.parse('2022-03'),15],[Date.parse('2022-04'),4],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),10],[Date.parse('2022-07'),13],[Date.parse('2022-08'),8],[Date.parse('2022-09'),8],],
                stack: 'curr'
            },{
                name: 'Closed 2022',
                data: [[Date.parse('2022-10'),5],[Date.parse('2022-02'),29],[Date.parse('2022-03'),29],[Date.parse('2022-04'),9],[Date.parse('2022-05'),7],[Date.parse('2022-06'),19],[Date.parse('2022-07'),28],[Date.parse('2022-08'),9],[Date.parse('2022-09'),19],],
                stack: 'curr'
            }   ]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-legend-item .highcharts-point,
.highcharts-legend-item .highcharts-graph {
  display: none
}
.customPoints, .points {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container_flow"></div>
```